# Default error page

Tags: meteor

I would like to define a default error page  in meteor. That is if application is crashing or other error occurs the user should be redirected to a "friendly" page  that says something like : system is unavailable , please contact  etc etc.
Is there any way to  accomplish this or something similar ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use BackboneJS([Backbone Router](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router)) for routing. With this code the session variable 'page_type' let's you know if you are on a wrong url.

```
var BackboneRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "/":            "default",
    ":error":       "list"
  },
  default: function () {
    Session.set("page_type", "default");
  },
  error: function () {
    Session.set("page_type", "error");
  }
});

Router = new BackboneRouter;

Meteor.startup(function () {
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

Now you can use the 'page_type' to tell the template engine which template to load.

```
Template.tmp.route = function () {
  if (Session.get("page_type") == "default") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }


<template name="tmp">
{{#if route}}
  {{> default}}
{{else}}
  {{> error}}
{{/if}}
</template>
```